# How to using "HeaderCell" of view-based NSOutlineView as group for "DataCell"?

Tags: objective-c, nsoutlineview

I have listed the items in "DataCell" view of NSOutlineView, but I do not know, how to put all of them into custom root group. I mean a default group of NSOutlineView items, but with some subviews (such as buttons or images). And one more, for example I have two groups of items, but one of them has subview, and second there has only a "Hide" toggle button, how can do something like that?

```
- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {
    if (![item isKindOfClass:[FSEntity class]]) {
        return [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell" owner:self];
    } else {
        NSTableCellView *cellView = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"DataCell" owner:self];
        cellView.textField.stringValue = [((FSEntity *)item) title];
        return cellView;
    }
}
```

We require the following methods to do that?

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isGroupItem:(id)item
```

However, can applications created with these features run on Tiger and Snow Leopard? Or would I have to resort back to cell-based table views? But how to do all of the above with the cell-based NSOutlineView, at least add Square Button into group of items?

**NOTE:** I enumerated items based of the protocol of NSURL and so the array does not have a root directory from which they are enumerated.